# Multiline datagridview cell to display First Line only

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`and I had set one column to `colLineNotes.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;`. The data of this column will be inputted by the user. If he double clicks on this column, a dialog form with textbox popups. Then he will types on it. After closing the form the data he inputs will passed to the cell.

My problem is when the users inputs multi line on the popup form let say 3 lines, the `DataGridView` shows two line but i only want to show the first line. See screenshot below. The first row is the current output. The 2nd row will be my preferred output but the 2nd and 3rd line is still there but hidden so that if the users double click it and wants to modify it will show up in the popup form.

[image: here]

Comment: You could set it to multiline the moment user double clicks the cell and set is back to single life after the user finishes typing in the form

Comment: The output became `1stLine2ndLine`.

Comment: Try setting AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells

Comment: Setting up that property will set my row height based on the value of the cell.

Comment: To satisfy such requirement, you can rely on `CellFormatting` event and set `e.value` to the first line of cell content. Also as another option you can just paint the first line of content yourself in `CellPainting` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved it. For future reference, the solution i made is to set the Top Padding of the column.

```
dgv.Columns["Instructions"].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 5, 0, 0);
```